# Relationship between p-values and effect size

Tags: p-value, multiple-comparisons, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I did a Wilcoxon signed rank test to understand whether there is a difference in average sales in 9 different counties. There are multiple pairs of counties that are significantly different.

Would it be fair in this case to say that p-values are representative of the effect size? i.e.: the pair with the lowest p-value differs the most in average sales?

Comment: Since the use of ranks destroys *all* information about actual sales, apart from their relative sizes, such an interpretation would have no justification.

Comment: I suspect that this question cannot be answered without clarifying what the shape of the distribution of differences in measures are. The signed rank test's null hypothesis is "The distribution of differences is both symmetric and centered on zero" with the alternative: ""The distribution of differences is either asymmetric or not centered on zero (or both)". Also what whuber said.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you are comparing across countries? What data do you have from each country?

Comment: Could you help me understand the best way to interpret differences here? I have th average sales from each county and some farm-level data for each farmer (arable land, yield, number of transaction etc). Basically, my end goal is to compare average sales across these 9 counties and find how to county with most/least sales differ from the rest

Answer (score 0):

In general, *p* values and effect size statistics address entirely different concepts.  I recommend keeping them entirely distinct in your mind.  ... You could devise circumstances where you keep e.g. the sample size and the hypothesis test the same, and that would make the *p* value related an effect size statistic.  But there's no reason to do this. You can simply calculate whatever effect size statistic you find informative. ...  For the signed rank test, the matched-pairs rank biserial correlation coefficient is good effect size statistic.  But if you wanted to present some other measure you could do that as well.

The signed rank test doesn't (directly) assess whether there is a difference in average sales.  If you are interested in the difference in average sales, I would recommend calculating this and presenting the results.  Likewise, you might be able to find an appropriate hypothesis test for the difference in average sales.

Comment: My line of thinking now is to take the counties with highest and lowest average sales and run a KW to check if they significantly differ.
If they do, I would then be interested to see how they differ across other factors (i.e.: possible reasons for the difference in sales between the two counties; I have variables for arable land, yield etc). Would it then be fair to run linear regressions for each variable of interest (county ~ arable land, county~ yield etc. for example)?

Comment: The p-value for that test would be (extremely) incorrect because you would no longer be comparing independent samples.  Instead, use a suitable procedure, such as ANOVA.

Comment: You probably don't want to isolate the counties with the highest and lowest sales.  If you are interested in what factors affect sales, it would make sense to include all counties.  Perhaps start with simple correlations of sales with e.g. yield, arable land.  However, you may want to build a more comprehensive model with multiple predictors with multiple linear regression or another kind of model.